# Convert the difference between two UTC times to local os time

Tags: datetime, lua

I am trying to count down the HH:MM:SS until the time occurs with two UTC timers. I need to calculate the difference between two UTC times and convert the difference to HH:MM:SS format for my os time

```
local firstUTC = '210000'
local secondUTC = os.date('!%H%M%S', os.time())
```

I want the result to be in the os.time() format of HH:MM:SS

Comment: os.time() format is number of seconds since 1970.  It contains year, month, and so on.  It cannot contain only time part of datetime.  This means you should add some date (for example, 2000-01-01) to the time to get a valid value of os.time format.